# Interactively watch code in python debugger pdb

Tags: python, debugging

Is is possible to watch the code being executed line by line interactively in python debugger `pdb` ?

For example in `gdb` one can press **^x + ^a** and it brings up a code window.

[image: GDB Screenshot]

I know I can see a bit of code using `list` but is there a `gdb` like option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not out of the box, but you can add [`Cmd.preloop()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cmd.html#cmd.Cmd.preloop) and [`Cmd.precmd()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cmd.html#cmd.Cmd.precmd) hooks of the `pdb.Pdb` command subclass in a `.pdbrc` file in your home directory, then drive a text editor to show the text.

This is the approach used by the [PdbSublimeTextSupport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PdbSublimeTextSupport) and [PdbTextMateSupport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PdbTextMateSupport) packages.

These packages simply read the current location from the `Cmd` subclass; `self.stack[self.curindex]` contains the current frame and line number, for example.

`PdbSublimeTextSupport` does:

```
def launch(self):
    frame, lineno = self.stack[self.curindex]
    filename = self.canonic(frame.f_code.co_filename)
    if exists(filename):
        command = 'subl -b "%s:%d"' % (filename, lineno)
        os.system(command)

def preloop(self):
    launch(self)

def precmd(self, line):
    launch(self)
    return line
```

and the Sublime Text editor opens `filename` at line `lineno`.

You can reference the [`bdb` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/bdb.html#bdb.Bdb)  (the bedrock on which PDB is built), together with the [`bdb.py`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/bdb.py) and [`pdb.py`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/pdb.py) source code, but the above example should be enough to drive just about any method of displaying the current source code lines.

Comment: Well I do have sublime text.Thanks for the info. Let me check :)